# Sending mail through Microsoft Graph returns Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a requirement where I need to send an email through an Office 365 account and after lot's googling, I found [Office 365 Connect ASP.NET MVC sample using Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-AspNetMVC-Microsoft-Graph-Connect).

Graph uses the below API to send the emails

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendmail
```

and below is the code where API is being called

```cs
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, SendMessageUrl))
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        string content = @"{
            ""message"": {
                ""subject"": ""Meet for lunch?"",
                ""body"": {
                ""contentType"": ""Text"",
                ""content"": ""The new cafeteria is open.""
                },
                ""toRecipients"": [
                {
                    ""emailAddress"": {
                    ""address"": ""myemailaddress""
                    }
                }
                ]
            },
            ""saveToSentItems"": ""false""
            }";
        request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using(HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                sendMessageResponse.Status = SendMessageStatusEnum.Sent;
                sendMessageResponse.StatusMessage = null;
            }
            else
            {
                sendMessageResponse.Status = SendMessageStatusEnum.Fail;
                sendMessageResponse.StatusMessage = response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But every time my request is getting failed with reason "**Internal Server Error**"

I am confused if this is a problem with the API or something wrong from my end.

Comment: Can you please include the response for a failed case including headers, if you are still able to repro it?

Comment: We validated the sample is working as expected. If you are still experiencing issues please let us know the entire error message you are getting back so we can investigate further